# Optimizing ListView In Android using CursorAdapter?

Tags: android, optimization, android-cursoradapter

How to optimize a `ListView` in `Android` which is being populated using a `CursorAdapter`? I am trying to create a `MediaPlayer` and the list appears with song titles and album art but the scrolling is very slow in the list.
How to optimize the `List` and `recycle view` in it?

All right i am adding my code here.....So i made this class extends `CursorAdapter` and then i made its object in classes i wanted it to populate it too...Then i set a type for each class and populated a specific version according to that type.

```
public class PopulatingListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private final static int ALL_SONGS_TYPE = 0;
private final static int ALBUM_SONGS = 1;
private final static int ARTIST_SONGS = 2;
private final static int ALBUM_TYPE = 3;
private final static int ARTIST_TYPE = 4;

private final LayoutInflater myInflater;

private int typeOfList;

public void setType(int type){
    typeOfList=type;
}

View myView=null;

public PopulatingListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public void initializingVariables(Activity activity){

}


@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(typeOfList==ALL_SONGS_TYPE)
    {   
        TextView songTitleNameAllSongs = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.all_song_title);
        songTitleNameAllSongs.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)));

        TextView songDisplayNameAllSongs = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.all_song_display);
        songDisplayNameAllSongs.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)));

        ImageView albumArtInAllSongs = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_art_all_songs_single_row);
        Cursor myCursor;
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID,
                               MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM,
                               MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART};
        myCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
        int row=0;
        if(myCursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            while(row<myCursor.getCount())
          {

            if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM)).equals(myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM))))
            {
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART)));
            if(bmp!=null)
                albumArtInAllSongs.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            else
                albumArtInAllSongs.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.head_10));
            }
            myCursor.moveToPosition(++row);
          }
        }

    }else if(typeOfList==ALBUM_TYPE)
    {   
        TextView albumCoverTitleInAllAlbums = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_cover_title);
        albumCoverTitleInAllAlbums.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM)));

        TextView artistAlbumTitleInAllAlbums = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artist_album_title);
        artistAlbumTitleInAllAlbums.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST)));

        ImageView albumArtInAllAlbum = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_single_row_album_art);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART)));
        if(bmp!=null)
            albumArtInAllAlbum.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        else
            albumArtInAllAlbum.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.head_10));        
    }else if(typeOfList==ARTIST_TYPE)
    {   
        TextView artistNameInAllArtist = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artists_single_name);
        artistNameInAllArtist.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST)));

    }else if(typeOfList==ALBUM_SONGS)
    {   
        TextView albumSongTitleNameInAlbumSongs = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.albums_songs_name_of_song);
        albumSongTitleNameInAlbumSongs.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)));

        TextView albumSongDisplayNameInAlbumSongs = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.albums_songs_name_of_album);
        albumSongDisplayNameInAlbumSongs.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM)));
    }else if(typeOfList==ARTIST_SONGS){
        TextView artistSongTitleNameInArtistSongs = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artist_song_title_name);
        artistSongTitleNameInArtistSongs.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)));

        TextView artistSongDisplayNameInArtistSongs = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artist_song_artist_name);
        artistSongDisplayNameInArtistSongs.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST)));
    }
  }


@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(typeOfList==ALL_SONGS_TYPE)
        {
            myView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.all_songs_single_row, parent, false);
        }else if(typeOfList==ALBUM_TYPE)
        {
            myView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.album_single_row, parent, false);
        }else if(typeOfList==ARTIST_TYPE)
        {
            myView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.artists_single_row, parent, false);
        }else if(typeOfList==ALBUM_SONGS)
        {
            myView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.albums_songs_single_row, parent, false);
        }else if(typeOfList==ARTIST_SONGS)
        {
            myView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.artists_song_single_row, parent, false);
        }
    return myView;
}
```

Comment: are you using a ViewBinder?

Comment: you mean the bindView method in cursorAdapter?

Comment: We should to see your code to understand how help to you

Comment: Posted the code and explained about it a bit in the question too

Comment: I had to run a query inside bind view to fetch the album art.....i couldn't fetch the album art in a single query for all songs

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing a lot of heavy downloading of images and audio files on the main (UI) thread.  To improve performance, large files should be downloaded on background threads so that they do not slow down the user interface.  When background threads complete their tasks, you would need a mechanism for them to notify your activity and pass on the loaded data.  There are several ways to accomplish this, but a full description would be far too long for this forum.

Here are some classes to research that can help with background loading:
[`Loader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html)
[`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Please look at these tutorials for more information:
[Processing Bitmaps Off the UI Thread](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html)
[Loading Data in the Background](http://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/index.html)

Comment: I am already using a cursorloader to load this data in the background...and I also know that there is a lot of downloading in this code but the thing is that I cannot run a query to fetch both songs and album art from different databases provided in the content provider...that's why I have to run a separate query to fetch album art

Comment: The databases for songs is Media and for album it is Albums...I cannot run these tables in the same loader and don't know how to use multiple loaders in the same class

Comment: It is common to have to load large media files after getting your initial cursor from CursorLoader.  Right now it looks like your initial cursor returns just text and URI links to your large media, which is what you want.  Now in your CursorAdapter.bindView() method, instead of running queries for the URI links directly on the UI thread, run them on an AsyncTask or a different Loader and provide them with callbacks to fill in their portion of the UI when they finish.  The tutorials provided in the original post are a good start.